# How to filter nested Objects and return the objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter this object of objects.

```js
const searchProduct = "aguas";

const unfilteredCurrentTemplates = {
  Aguascalientes: {
    productTemplate: {
      id: 351,
      created_at: "2019-03-05 22:29:49",
      updated_at: "2019-03-05 22:29:49",
      name: "Aguascalientes License Plate Hat",
      template: "prt_Aguascalientes.ai",
      fonts: null,
      custom_text: null,
      r: "0",
      g: "0",
      b: "0",
      top: "44",
      spacing: "68",
      relationId: null,
      aWidth: null,
      aHeight: null,
      productGroup: "20",
      shopifyId: "9935005454",
    },
    colorVariants: false,
  },
  Alabama: {
    productTemplate: {
      id: 1013,
      created_at: "2019-02-12 00:19:56",
      updated_at: "2019-02-12 00:19:56",
      name: "Alabama Plate Hat",
      template: "prt_Alabama.ai",
      fonts: "1",
      custom_text: "2",
      r: "0",
      g: "0",
      b: "0",
      top: "40",
      spacing: "77",
      relationId: null,
      aWidth: null,
      aHeight: null,
      productGroup: "20",
      shopifyId: "1307208155204",
    },
    colorVariants: false,
  },
  Alaska: {
    productTemplate: {
      id: 383,
      created_at: "2019-03-19 22:00:26",
      updated_at: "2019-03-19 22:00:26",
      name: "Alaska Plate Hat",
      template: "prt_Alaska.ai",
      fonts: "1",
      custom_text: "2",
      r: "42",
      g: "41",
      b: "95",
      top: "53",
      spacing: "73",
      relationId: null,
      aWidth: null,
      aHeight: null,
      productGroup: "20",
      shopifyId: "1927328399448",
    },
    colorVariants: false,
  },
  "Arizona 2018": {
    productTemplate: {
      id: 384,
      created_at: "2019-03-19 22:00:26",
      updated_at: "2019-03-19 22:00:26",
      name: "Arizona 2018 Plate Hat",
      template: "prt_Arizona-other.ai",
      fonts: "1",
      custom_text: "2",
      r: "30",
      g: "72",
      b: "69",
      top: "34",
      spacing: "81",
      relationId: null,
      aWidth: null,
      aHeight: null,
      productGroup: "20",
      shopifyId: "1337703858264",
    },
    colorVariants: false,
  },
  Arizona: {
    productTemplate: {
      id: 304,
      created_at: "2019-02-12 00:19:56",
      updated_at: "2019-02-12 00:19:56",
      name: "Arizona Plate Hat",
      template: "prt_Arizona.ai",
      fonts: "1",
      custom_text: "2",
      r: "0",
      g: "0",
      b: "0",
      top: "40",
      spacing: "79",
      relationId: null,
      aWidth: null,
      aHeight: null,
      productGroup: "20",
      shopifyId: "9503320398",
    },
    colorVariants: false,
  },
};
```

My attempt is:

```js
const filter = Object.keys(unfilteredCurrentTemplates)
  .filter((item) => item.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchProduct.toLowerCase()))
  .map((obj) => unfilteredCurrentTemplates[obj]);

console.log(filter);
```

This returns back an array of the nested object:

```
    {
        "productTemplate": {
            "id": 351,
            "created_at": "2019-03-05 22:29:49",
            "updated_at": "2019-03-05 22:29:49",
            "name": "Aguascalientes License Plate Hat",
            "template": "prt_Aguascalientes.ai",
            "fonts": null,
            "custom_text": null,
            "r": "0",
            "g": "0",
            "b": "0",
            "top": "44",
            "spacing": "68",
            "relationId": null,
            "aWidth": null,
            "aHeight": null,
            "productGroup": "20",
            "shopifyId": "9935005454"
        },
        "colorVariants": false
    }
```

I need to keep the same structure of ulfiteredCurrentTemplates but with the items filtered to what I'm searching for.

Comment: TL;DR from the duplicate `Object.fromEntries( Object.entries( unfilteredCurrentTemplates).filter(([key]) => key.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchProduct) ) )`